# How do I return only the earliest date in an SQL query but include other columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-core

I have a SQL View which looks at a table of data and brings back the results with a few joins and a subquery.  The subquery is designed to bring back the period with the earliest date, however, because I try to return a few additional columns in that subquery, I still get mutliple rows.  Here is my entire view.

```
SELECT r.Id, 
       r.Broker, 
       com.EarliestDate AS CommencementStart,
       rp.Frequency,
       rp.Duration,

FROM dbo.Requirement AS r LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT 
          RequirementId, 
          MIN(Commencement) AS EarliestDate 
      FROM RequirementPeriod 
      GROUP BY RequirementId) 
    AS com ON r.Id= com.RequirementId
```

I want it to bring back the row with the earliest date only.  I can get that to work by using the following `SELECT`

```
(SELECT RequirementId, Frquency, Duration, MIN(Commencement) AS EarliestDate FROM RequirementPeriod GROUP BY RequirementId, Frequency, Duration) AS com ON r.Id= com.RequirementId
```

The problem here is that, if I want to include additional columns in this sub query, as above, I start to get multiple rows because it's grouping by each column given.

Is there a way I can take the earliest date but include duration and frequency without it taking multiple rows or by not using grouping?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear *which* row you want,

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that what you want is `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT r.Id, r.Broker, 
       rp.Commencement AS CommencementStart,
       rp.Frequency, rp.Duration,
FROM dbo.Requirement r OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) rp.*
      FROM RequirementPeriod rp
      WHERE r.Id = rp.RequirementId
      ORDER BY Commencement
     ) rp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
with rp as
(
    SELECT *, row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by RequirementId ORDER BY Commencement) from dbo.RequirementPeriod  
)
select *
from dbo.Requirement as r
join rp on (rp.RequirementId = r.id) and (rp.row = 1)
```